# Running some startup tasks in Configure of Azure FunctionsStartup

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a function that is bound to a QueueTrigger. In this function I generate a file and write this to a Blob Storage.

But before writing (uploading) the file I want to make sure that the container exists. Is the `Configure` method in the startup class that inherits `FunctionsStartup` the right place? It feels wrong to do it every time the trigger runs, isn't it?

I'm using DI to supply my function class some services.

```cs
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger(MyQueueName, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
    MyObject queueMessage, ILogger log)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyFileContent");

    // Check if container exists - but not everytime?

    var blobClient = new BlobClient(_settings.ConnectionString, _settings.ContainerName, _settings.FileName);

    await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream, true);
}
```

```cs
using MyApp.FunctionApp;
using MyApp.FunctionApp.Options;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace MyApp.FunctionApp
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // Some startup tasks here like ensuring existence of a Blob Container?
            
            builder.Services.AddOptions<Storage>().Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
            {
                configuration.GetSection("Storage").Bind(settings);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the frequency of how often you want to check, you could even do something as simple as this:

```
//shared variable for all instances that run on the same VM
private static bool HaveCheckedBlobContainer = false;
```

Then, on each invocation:

```
if (!HaveCheckedBlobContainer)
{
   //perform check ...
   HaveCheckedBlobContainer = true; 
}
```

I'll generally have an Initialize() method to set up some expensive instances that need to be stored in static member variables. I'll call Initialize() on each invocation, and use a check such as

```
_someMemberVariable ??= getItFromMyDiContainerOrInstantiateId();
```

So that it's only executed once, regardless of invocation count.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the `??=` operator!